File Outline display wrong (stacked instead of seperated)
My file outline after downloading a compiled .pdf from Overleaf is displayed wrong. I have the following code
\input{content/Section_1}

\section{Section_2}
\input{content/Section_2}

\section{Section_3}
\input{content/Section_3}

\section{Section_4}
\input{content/Section_4}

But the file outline in my PDF is as follows:

Section_2

1.2 Subsection_2.1
1.2.1 Subsection_2.2
1.2.2 Section_3
1.2.2.1 Subsection_3.1
1.2.2.2 Subsection_3.2
1.2.2.3 Section_4
I hope it makes it clear. In words: It basically stacks up my sections as subsections of a previous section which gives me the illustrated tree structure.

Welcome to TeX.SE. Do you mean Bookmark in PDF? For better understanding, please provide MWE

I don't think bookmarks but the document outline that is usually displayed on the left (e.g., in Adobe Reader or when opening in the browser). What exactly is the MWE?

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Don't you get an error from using _ outside of math mode?

MWE means https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

What's in those files you're \inputing?
